# swift URLCache after IOS 12 update

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlcache

I extended `URLCache` to implement offline browsing of a web site in IOS app using UIWebView. Before IOS 12 every thing was working fine. `cachedResponse`, `getCachedResponse`, `storeCachedResponse` and `storeCachedResponse` are called as intended, but after IOS 12 update only `cachedResponse` and `getCachedResponse` are called, so no caching is done now. I tried to change the `cachePolicy` property but nothing happened. Is there something new in `URLCache`.

Comment: Is this on production app from the App Store? What iOS version do you have your app set to support?

Comment: No its not on the App Store. It supports IOS 9.3

Comment: Show the code you are using for the ones that are not working.

Comment: @NizarAhmed did you find a way to solve this problem?